# .Net Standard 2.0 Generate NuGet package including projects in the same solution and NuGet packages

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, .net-standard-2.0

I've read some questions similar to mine here, but they were answered about a year ago, the idea is to check if is there any news regarding this.

Assuming that i have a solution with the following structure:

- DotNetSolution

  - DotNetProjectReferencingSubProjects    (this project is the one for generating nuget package)
  - ProjectA
  - ProjectB
  - ProjectC

    -NugetPackageInsideProjectC

**Structure Explanation**

The idea of this project is to retrive documents from public/private clouds, but i wanted to make the call transparent to the caller, so i architeture the solution like this:

- CloudHandler.Library.csproj
- CloudHandler.Services.Factory.csproj
- CloudHandler.Plugin.Aws.csproj
- CloudHandler.Plugin.PrivateCloud1.csproj
- CloudHandler.Plugin.Gcp.csproj
- CloudHandler.Plugin.PrivateCloud2.csproj

**CloudHandler.Library.csproj** references **CloudHandler.Services.Factory.csproj**

**CloudHandler.Services.Factory.csproj**
references

- CloudHandler.Plugin.Aws.csproj
- CloudHandler.Plugin.PrivateCloud1.csproj
- CloudHandler.Plugin.Gcp.csproj
- CloudHandler.Plugin.PrivateCloud2.csproj

**CloudHandler.Plugin.Aws.csproj** references **AWSSDK.S3**

When I pack CloudHandler.Library or even CloudHandler.Services.Factory, the project that use this references throws an exception, because it can't find AWSSDK.S3 reference.

How do I pack  DotNetProjectReferencingSubProjects including all references? (projects and NuGet packages that those projects reference to?)

Thanks in advance.

I've read some ideas that sugest to add csproj files and it's referenced on nuspec. 
Thinking about maintaining the project in the future, it will be hard for someone with no knowledge to figure it out.

Comment: can you clarify? it is *almost never intended* for `DotNetProjectReferencingSubProjects` to *bundle directly* `ProjectA`, `ProjectB` and `ProjectC`; usually, they would all be their *own* nupkg, and `DotNetProjectReferencingSubProjects` simply advertises a package-dependency on the others. That is *correct and normal*. If that isn't what you want, can you be more specific? (and of course, you'd need to package and deploy all of them)

Comment: I've eddited the question, i don't know if will help to understand. "usually, they would all be their own nupkg". (I've read about it too, but the idea is to encapsulate it)

Comment: With the update, it *sounds* like the problem you're fighting here is "transitive dependency chains"; this problem was pretty much solved *completely* in the switch to SDK-style projects; are you using an SDK-style project? i.e. a new-style csproj? (which is fine targeting .NET Framework; it isn't just for .NET Core)

Comment: I've never heard about this that you told me, but i just googled it and apparently  the project is based on sdk-style

Comment: "the project that use this references" is? if so: it should automatically explode the dependency tree, assuming you're using *anything like* recent build tools; so you should never see a problem with AWSSDK.S3, if the tree takes that dependency somewhere

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer, i was trying to upload it to git, https://github.com/viniandrade00/cloudHandler

Comment: ok; I've cloned that, and run `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` and everything works... do you see something different?

Comment: at this point, no. I have problem when i create a nuget pack from CloudHandler.Library and reference it in another project. saying that couldn't found AWS reference

Comment: tip: include a project that *actually shows the problem*; I've created a console exe with a dependency on `CloudHandler.Library`, and at can see `FileStorage` just fine (which comes from the AWS plugin right at the other end of the tree). So: can you show a project that *actually demonstrates the problem you're seeing*?

Comment: and if I look at the bin output: I have AWSSDK.Core.dll and AWSSDK.S3.dll - looks like it worked

Comment: but did you referenced the project? Or did your created a nuget package of it ?

Comment: I've upload the example project with error https://github.com/viniandrade00/cloudHandler/blob/master/ConsoleApp.472.7z

Comment: switching to nuget package reference (to a private package store); the *immediate* dependency is fine, but you need nupkg for all the other layers - you need to create CloudHandler.Services.Factory nupkg, etc; once again, from my very first comment: "they would all be their *own* nupkg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitive dependencies *work fine*, but you need to create (and upload/manage) packages for *every layer*; it isn't enough just to create a nupkg for `CloudHandler.Library` - you need one for *everything in the tree*.

With that done locally using a private package cache that has:

- CloudHandler.Domain.Plugins.Aws.1.0.0.nupkg
- CloudHandler.Domain.Plugins.Azure.1.0.0.nupkg
- CloudHandler.Domain.Plugins.Gcp.1.0.0.nupkg
- CloudHandler.Domain.Providers.1.0.0.nupkg
- CloudHandler.Infrastructure.Contracts.Plugin.1.0.0.nupkg
- CloudHandler.Infrastructure.Contracts.Provider.1.0.0.nupkg
- CloudHandler.Library.1.0.0.nupkg
- CloudHandler.Services.Factory.1.0.0.nupkg

then I can create a test project with:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CloudHandler.Library" Version="1.0.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

and it all works correctly. The build output includes AWSSDK.Core.dll and ASWWDK.S3.dll, among others. The test project can see all of the types in the expanded dependency tree, despite only having a direct dependency on `CloudHandler.Library`.

Depending on your needs, this *may* serve as impetus to be slightly less granular with your packages. Or it might be just right for what you need.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I'll try to change my project and devops workflow to follow your recomendations.

Comment: Do you have any best aproach generate nuget packages of a project like this in devops?

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade with SDK-style projects (new-style csproj), it is all automatic...

Comment: do you have any documents or articles regarding this?

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade [dotnet pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-dotnet-cli), or `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` and `dotnet build`; or look on the left menu on that page for how to do the same with MSBuild